# Vue mustache templates not working unless I defer JavaScript file link

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a simple Vue app. I am experiencing different results based on where my scripts are located in the head and whether I'm using defer. Without defer, the mustache templates are rendered as is without Vue (e.g., `{{ playerHealth }}` rather than the number assigned to it in the Vue data), but if I add defer to the app.js link (which follows the Vue CDN link), it renders normally.

Mustache templates rendered as HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Demon Slayer</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <!-- Only using CSS for Foundation, no JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-xpOKVlYXzQ3P03j397+jWFZLMBXLES3IiryeClgU5og= sha384-gP4DhqyoT9b1vaikoHi9XQ8If7UNLO73JFOOlQV1RATrA7D0O7TjJZifac6NwPps sha512-AKwIib1E+xDeXe0tCgbc9uSvPwVYl6Awj7xl0FoaPFostZHOuDQ1abnDNCYtxL/HWEnVOMrFyf91TDgLPi9pNg==" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

</head>
```

Same code in head but adding defer to app.js link -- works as expected:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<script defer src="app.js"></script>
```

This is strange to me because I thought that if I didn't use defer at all, the HTML would render, then Vue would download, then the app.js with the Vue instance would replace the mustache template HTML with the Vue data.

Why do I need to use defer for the mustache template to render with Vue?

Also weird, maybe related: if I use defer on both scripts and place at the end of the head, the mustache template HTML appears briefly (before the expected Vue value), but if I place before the stylesheet links, only the Vue version of the template mustache shows up. I'm not sure why it would affect anything.

Maybe these issues are related to my viewing the app with the Visual Studio Code Live Server extension.

Full code:

app.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    playerHealth: 100,
    demonHealth: 100,
    gameIsRunning: false
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Demon Slayer</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
  <script defer src="app.js"></script>

  <!-- Only using CSS for Foundation, no JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-xpOKVlYXzQ3P03j397+jWFZLMBXLES3IiryeClgU5og= sha384-gP4DhqyoT9b1vaikoHi9XQ8If7UNLO73JFOOlQV1RATrA7D0O7TjJZifac6NwPps sha512-AKwIib1E+xDeXe0tCgbc9uSvPwVYl6Awj7xl0FoaPFostZHOuDQ1abnDNCYtxL/HWEnVOMrFyf91TDgLPi9pNg==" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app" class="grid-container">
  <h1>DEMON SLAYER</h1>
  <section class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell small-6">
      <h2>YOU</h2>
      <div class="health-bar">
        <div class="health-bar" style="background-color: green; margin: 0; color: white;">
          {{ playerHealth }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-6">
      <h2>DEMON</h2>
      <div class="health-bar">
        <div class="health-bar" style="background-color: green; margin: 0; color: white;">
          {{ demonHealth }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="cell controls">
    <button id="start-game">NEW GAME</button>
  </section>
  <section class="cell controls">
    <button id="attack">ATTACK</button>
    <button id="special-attack">SPECIAL ATTACK</button>
    <button id="heal">HEAL</button>
    <button id="give-up">GIVE UP</button>
  </section>
  <section class="cell log">
    <ul>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Metamorphous", cursive;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.health-bar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: auto;
  transition: width 500ms;
}

.controls, .log {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #ccc;
}

.turn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.log ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.log ul li {
  margin: 5px;
}

.log ul .player-turn {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #e4e8ff;
}

.log ul .monster-turn {
  color: red;
  background-color: #ffc0c1;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#start-game {
  background-color: #7ad47a;
}

#start-game:hover {
  background-color: #6cc56c;
}

#attack {
  background-color: #ff7367;
}

#attack:hover {
  background-color: #ff3f43;
}

#special-attack {
  background-color: #ffaf4f;
}

#special-attack:hover {
  background-color: #ff9a2b;
}

#heal {
  background-color: #87cefa;
}

#heal:hover {
  background-color: #76bde9;
}

#give-up {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

#give-up:hover {
  background-color: #acacac;
}
```

Comment: You need to add your app.js at the end of the <body> tag, not the <head> tag. Adding the defer attribute simulates this behaviour. See more: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Using a script in the head with defer is faster than including it at the end of the body because the script is asynchronously downloaded. https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/#no-defer-or-async-in-the-body